# JAXB adding annotated classes with new JAR

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, annotations

Have following situation:
A class with a List field like:

```
@XMLType
@XMLAccessType(XMLAccessorType.FIELD) 
@XMLRootElement(name = "container")
public class ListContainer {
   @XMLElementWrapper(name="elements")
   private List<Element> elements = new ArrayList<>();

....
}
```

The Element class is an abstract JAXB annotated class with @XMLRootElement annotation like:

```
@XMLType
@XMLRootElemenent
public abstract class Element {
....
}
```

These classes define some kind of Framework and users shall be able to add own implementations of Element class within own JAR packages. What I would like to achieve, is that after unmarshalling I would have in elements field of the instance of class ListContainer class instances which were introduced as extensions to the framework. For instance let say there is a class DummyElement in some other ext1.jar, which is in the class path, and it looks like following:

```
@XMLType
@XMLRootElement(name = "dummy")
public class DummyElement extends Element {
   ....
}
```

in ext2.jar I will have EasyElement like:

```
@XMLType
@XMLRootElement(name = "easy")
public class EasyElement extends Element {
...
}
```

in xml there on the place I would have something like:

```
<container>
    <elements>
        <dummy>....</dummy>
        <easy>...</easy>
        <easy>....</easy>
        <dummy>...</dummy>
    </elements>
</container>
```

expected result should be, that unmarshalled instance of ListContainer class will have 2 DummyElement instances and 2 EasyElement instances in elements fields.

So far if I leave ListContainer class annotated like this - I will have nothing in list. If I annotated with @XMLAnyElement(lax=true) then I will have ElementNSImpl instances.

Thank you for ideas in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Update:

The solution is in control over creation of JAXBContext. I created service interface, which delivers me a list of classes required for context like:

```
public interface XMLContextProvider {
    Set<Class> getJAXBContextClasses();
}
```

Then I created in framework a class which implements this interface and lists all classes I require from side of the framework. The same was done for extensions. The classes registered in META-INF/services - see ServiceLoader. Then I created a utility class, which utilises the ServiceLoader to find all providers and creates the JAXBContext with the list of all classes gathered from all providers. With this context it is possible to Marshal and Unmarshal. Additionally as I utilise JAX-RS I have created a Resolver for JAXBContext:

```
@Provider
public class XMLContextResolver implements ContextResolver<JAXBContext> {
    private JAXBContext ctx;

    public XMLContextResolver() {
        ctx = <here goes call to utility class>
    }

    @Override
    public JAXBContext getContext(Class<?> type) {
        if (this.classes.contains(type)) {
            return this.ctx;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```